# Parse a website and turn html content into variables within PowerShell

Tags: html, class, powershell, url

How would I call a URL and turn the page content into variables to use in PowerShell?

The HTML page looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<span class="server1var1">8</span>
<span class="server1var2">2</span>

<span class="server2var1">5</span>
<span class="server2var2">1</span>

</body>
</html>
```

Then in PowerShell I want these variables:

```
$server1var1 = "8"
$server1var2 = "2"

$server2var1 = "5"
$server2var2 = "1"
```

Accepting the answer below with one modification to make it work for me. Changing `$_.textContent` to `$_.innerhtml` solved the issue.

```
$content = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://urltomysite'
$content.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName('span') | ForEach-Object { 
    New-Variable -Name $_.className -Value $_.innerhtml
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Invoke-WebRequest` cmdlet to retrieve the content of your website. Then use the `getElementsByTagName` of the `ParsedHtml` property to retrieve all `span` tags. Finally turn them into a variable using the `New-Variable` cmdlet:

```
$content = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://gameadmin.zerosurvival.com/servercodes.php'
$content.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName('span') | ForEach-Object { 
    New-Variable -Name $_.className -Value $_.textContent 
    }
```

After you run this, if you type `$server1var1` you will get `8`.

Comment: Running that exact code (changing only the Uri to a page of mine), I get no output for $server1var1. 
`$content = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://urltoyoursite'
$content.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName('span') | ForEach-Object { 
    New-Variable -Name $_.className -Value $_.textcontent 
    }

echo "$server1var1"`
I get no errors either.

Comment: This code is working since I hosted your html in IIS and testet it. Is the URL public - can you share it? Does the HTML contains a span tag with class name `server1var1`? Does it have a value?

Comment: This is working as expected. after I run this, the `$server1var1` contains `8`.

Comment: doesnt work in my pc : error : New-Variable : Impossible de lier l'argument au paramètre « Name », car il a la valeur Null.

Comment: What do you get if you run `(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://gameadmin.zerosurvival.com/servercodes.php').ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName('span') | select className, textContent`

Comment: Changing `textContent` to `innerhtml`  I get http://i.imgur.com/M6QQo2J.png

Updating your original code from $_.textcontent to $_.innerhtml works!! Is there a reason why this would work for me, but textContent would not?

Answer (score 1):

other solution

```
$template=@'
<span class="{servername*:server1var1}">{value:8}</span>
<span class="{servername*:server1var2}">{value:2}</span>
'@

(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://www.google.fr').ParsedHtml.body.innerHTML | ConvertFrom-String -TemplateContent $template
```

Comment: While this may work in the provided example, this is not the way you want to parse a html file. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1163423. Also it doesn't set variables...

Comment: this solution is a answer which work, he can choice to use or not (but your respect condition but your solution doesnt work in my pc...)

Comment: On the link you gave the opinions are shared